# Selenium return blank for specific pages, but works for others

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

I am new to selenium, I want to use selenium to crawl this website
http://www.customs.gov.cn/customs/302249/index.html, but I get a blank page like this. But when I try to get http://www.customs.gov.cn, it could return the right results. I do not think it is a problem with selenium, I search a lot, but do not know why, could you please help me? Thanks.
Here is my code:

```py
    from selenium import webdriver # selenium import webdriver
    import time
    url = 'http://www.customs.gov.cn/customs/302249/index.html'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # 声明调用Chrome
    driver.get(url) #
```

this is the returned blank page.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the url http://www.customs.gov.cn/customs/302249/index.html opens in an incognito window in chrome before retrying. The URL didn't work for me.
Report the client regarding a blank page. You may be seeing the cached version of the page. CTRL + F5 will help you get a fresh copy of the page as well.

Remember, Selenium simply asks browsers to open a page. It doesn't open the page itself.

Comment: Thanks, the link works for me. But this is a government website, maybe it is not available for you. I do not understand your CTRL+F5, I tried that, but nothing changes

Comment: CTRL + F5 is for a hard refresh. This tells the browser to load the page again from the scratch.

Comment: are you able to open the website on any other browser? If yes, try using chrome with a profile. That may also help